# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined UsersReportingComponent.html

Tags: angular

**users.reporting.component.html:**

```
<div class="container"

    <form (ngSubmit)="processForm()">

        <div class="form group" >
            <label for="id">Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.id">
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
        </div>

        <div class="form group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="date">Joining Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.date">
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
            <label for="address">Addrress</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.address">
        </div>

        <div class="form group">
            <label for="status">Status</label>
            <input type="text" name="status" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.status">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
</div>
```

**users.reporting.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/user';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared_service/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-reporting',
  templateUrl: './users-reporting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-reporting.component.css']
})
export class UsersReportingComponent implements OnInit {      
  private user: User;

  constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this._userService.getter();            
  }
  processForm() {
    if (this.user.id == undefined) {
      this._userService.createUser(this.user).subscribe((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        this._router.navigate(['/user-listing']);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    } else {
      this._userService.updateUser(this.user).subscribe((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        this._router.navigate(['/user-listing']);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me out... I have an error in my project, the error is like this:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UsersReportingComponent.html:53)
>           at Object.debugUpdateDirectives 
>           at checkAndUpdateView 
>           at callViewAction 
>           at execComponentViewsAction 
>           at checkAndUpdateView 
>           at callViewAction 
>           at execEmbeddedViewsAction 
>           at checkAndUpdateView 
>           at callViewAction

Comment: Are you sure you have a user?

Comment: `user?.id` try making the id optional.

Comment: yeah! i have a user

Comment: i have tried  this user?.id  ..but the still same error

Comment: Your `user` is `private` make it public.

Comment: One note regarding convention, `user` should not be `private`. It is used by the template.

Comment: yeah!  you both are right sir, but i have still error

Comment: @RohitPrajapati same error???

Comment: @Jai yes sir same error

Comment: Please share the code for `userService.getter();`. Is that an `Observable`?

Comment: And your interface User definitely has an id? After trying @pierreduc 's answer below, maybe just console.log(this.user) just to be sure.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes sir ...

Comment: @rrd yes sir ....export class User {
    id:Number;
    email:string;
    date:Date;
    address:string;
    status:string;
}

Comment: Try number instead of Number

Comment: @RohitPrajapati, I'd take a step back an update your question with this information instead of the comments. Add `getter()`, add the `User` class or interface.

Comment: @rrd still same erro

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky sir i have added but still same error

Answer (score 0):

You never set `user`:

```
export class UsersReportingComponent implements OnInit {
   user: User = new User();

  //...
}
```

Make sure to initialise your class fields before `ngOnInit` by setting it in the constructor or directly on the field, or use the `?.` save navigation operator inside your template: `[(ngModel)]="user?.id"`

Also as stated in the comments, don't make your user field `private`, because otherwise the AOT compilation will fail

Comment: @RohitPrajapati then you have not posted the entire template, the error seems to be at line 53 of your template. Or your userService.getter() is not returning a user but undefined

Comment: sir this is at line 53:    <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.id">

Comment: you should show the entire `UserService`, because the user returned from it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have to change this:

```
private user: User;
```

to this:

```
public user: User;
```

Private properties are only available inside the class but template is outside.

Comment: thanks for respond sir...but i have still same error

Comment: @RohitPrajapati then it looks like the other answer is the solution for your issue. Did you try that?

Comment: yes @Jai sir ...i have tried every solution but still same error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are retrieving `user` data using `this._userService.getter();` in `ngOnInit()`. You could use `*ngIf` to test whether the `user` has been loaded prior to rendering the form to avoid this error:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="processForm()" *ngIf="user">
// ...
</form>
```

Another option would be to simply initialize some default values like `''` for `string` for the `user` object until the `getter()` has resolved:

```
user: User = {
  id: 42,
  name: '',
  email: '',
  // ... remaining properties
}
```

Also, are you sure you are using `getter()` correctly? Assuming your call is something along the lines of:

```
getter()
  return this.http.get<User>('/some/api/url')
}
```

You'd consume that like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._userService.getter().subcribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: getter(){
    return this.user;
  }

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this._userService.getter();
    
  }